# How to burn a Fungible token owned by a program in a vault account (PDA)?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, spl-token, burn

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(idx:u64)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    // Derived PDAs
    #[account(
        init,
        payer= user_sending,
        seeds=[b"state".as_ref(), user_sending.key().as_ref(), mint_of_token_sent.key().as_ref(), idx.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space =8 +8 +32+ 32+ 32+ 8 +1
    )]
    state: Account<'info, State>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer= user_sending,
        seeds=[b"wallet".as_ref(), user_sending.key().as_ref(), mint_of_token_sent.key().as_ref(), bridge_idx.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
        token::mint= mint_of_token_sent,
        token::authority=state,
    )]
    vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    user_sending: Signer<'info>,
    mint_of_token_sent: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(mut,
        constraint=user_sending_token_account.owner==user_sending.key(),
        constraint=user_sending_token_account.mint==mint_of_token_sent.key(),
    )]
    user_sending_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(idx:u64)]
pub struct BurnTx<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds=[b"state".as_ref(), user_sending.key().as_ref(), mint_of_token_sent.key().as_ref(), idx.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one= user_sending,
        has_one=mint_of_token_sent,
    )]
    state: Account<'info, State>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds=[b"wallet".as_ref(), user_sending.key().as_ref(), mint_of_token_sent.key().as_ref(), idx.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    user_sending: Signer<'info>,
    mint_of_token_sent: Account<'info, Mint>,

    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

**My endpoint:**

```
pub fn burn_tx(ctx: Context<BurnTx>, idx: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let bump = ctx.bumps.state.to_le_bytes();
        let binding = ctx.accounts.user_sending.key();
        let mint_of_token_sent_pk = ctx.accounts.mint_of_token_sent.key();
        let idx_bytes = idx.to_le_bytes();
        let inner = vec![
            b"state".as_ref(),
            binding.as_ref(),
            mint_of_token_sent_pk.as_ref(),
            idx_bytes.as_ref(),
            bump.as_ref(),
        ];

        let outer = vec![inner.as_slice()];

        let burn_instruction = Burn {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint_of_token_sent.to_account_info(),
            from: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.state.to_account_info(),
        };

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            burn_instruction,
            outer.as_slice(),
        );

        anchor_spl::token::burn(cpi_ctx, ctx.accounts.state.amount)?;

        let should_close = {
            ctx.accounts.escrow_wallet.reload()?;
            ctx.accounts.escrow_wallet.amount == 0
        };

        if should_close {
            let ca = CloseAccount {
                account: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info(),
                destination: ctx.accounts.user_sending.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.state.to_account_info(),
            };

            let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                ca,
                outer.as_slice(),
            );

            anchor_spl::token::close_account(cpi_ctx)?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
```

I got this error:

```
Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account.
```

I am using anchor framework verison 0.29.0.